# Has anyone attempted making a ring that combined Will and Fear?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

In *Green Lantern* they make two rings: one for the yellow power of fear, and one for the green power of will.

Has anyone in the Green Lantern setting attempted to make a single ring that combined the two, so that they would be able to master both at once? Has this idea been explored anywhere before?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to focus on concrete examples, as it seemed (in my opinion) a bit too focused on pure speculation, which can make it difficult to answer.  If you disagree with my edits, please feel free to change it further, or even roll back my edits to your original version.

Comment: This may be a bit contrived considering that I don't remember a single instance in canon where someone tried to combine the aspects of any two colors into one ring, let alone Green and Yellow specifically.

Comment: @Yawus Its no more contrived than [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/could-the-enterprise-beam-a-vampire-into-a-house-she-didnt-have-permission-to-e), which received almost 100 upvotes.

Comment: @Beofett I note the large amount of upvotes, but lack of conclusive (accepted) answer. While this may be a valid question, the answer to both questions would have to involve a large amount of speculation that may or may not have a basis in canon.

Comment: @Yawus Questions that involve [in-universe speculation and extrapolation are currently considered on-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/358#358).  Note that "on-topic" doesn't necessarily mean it is a *good* question.... I've tried to improve the original version (which was far more speculative), but please feel free to add further improvements if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Edited the title so it matches the body and is less speculation-bait.

Comment: @Beofett Well, given that, I've tried my attempt at speculating on an answer.

Comment: @Yawus the Blue Lanterns require proximity to a Green Lantern in order to utilize the full potential of their own rings.

Comment: Harley Quinn wielded a dual ring, half Black, half Red. Can be read in Harley's Little Black Book. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbnYa.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbnYa.jpg)

Answer (score 14):

#### No, the sources of the powers of the Emotional Color Spectrum are all unique. Even though all of the powers utilize a battery construct, each construct's origin was formed differently and how those powers function usually means these powers are unable to be used in concert, by a single user.

- Some derive their power primarily from or through the wielder; i.e. Red, Indigo, Orange
- Others from powerful entities such as, the Guardians, Zamorans, Parallax or the Life Entity; i.e. Green, Violet, Yellow, White
- Or directly from the Universe or even from beyond the Universe itself i.e. Blue, Black

Each power is designed to resonate with the corresponding ring and emotional state. Most of the powers are incompatible or even antithetical with the other powers or emotional states.

[image]

- **Red:** Red rings channel rage and hate. Created by Atrocitus sacrificing the magical energies of other sorcerous beings called the Five Inversions and his own nearly limitless hatred, he was able to create the Red Central Power battery and became the first Red Ring. The power of the Red is to channel the hatred, rage and frustration of their wielder. The power of the Red is bound to the lifeforce of the wielder and cannot be removed without the death of the wielder. The Red power is vulnerable to the power of Hope and can be drained by the Blue Lantern wielders. Red Lanterns are also vulnerable to love and can die if they fall in love.
- **Orange:** The Orange power rings are powered by avarice, also known as greed. The Orange power can absorb energies from other rings but cannot absorb constructs produced by violet or blue power rings. The Orange power is particularly resistant to the Green. The orange power can be nullified by the presence of a Blue ring wielder.
- **Yellow:** Unlike the Green Rings of the Corps which operate by channeling pure willpower, these rings which are forged on Qward channel pure fear. Several versions of these rings have been created, but recently they have become the primary weapon of the Sinestro Corps, seeking out individuals to battle the Green Lantern Corps who have the ability to instill great fear. The primal source of this power was the demonic force called Parallax.
- **Green:** The Green power is fueled by willpower. At the enter of the emotional spectrum, it is not an emotion but the control of one's emotional state which powers the Green ring. The Green ring was once vulnerable to the Yellow power, but much less so than in the past. The presence of the Blue power can greatly increase the performance of wielders of the Green energy supercharging their rings powers.
- **Blue:** The Blue Power Rings are shown to symbolize hope, and were forged by Ganthet and Sayd, two former Guardians of Oa. The Blue energy of hope has an infallible connection to the universe. Hope is the most powerful of light, and thus the universe speaks through it. The Blue energy is one of the most powerful energies and is capable of augmenting the Green energy and depleting the Yellow as well as potentially neutralizing the Orange, Red and Yellow energies.
- **Violet:** The Violet power rings, forged by the Zamarons, (an offshoot of the Malthusians) are shown to be fueled by the emotion of love. The Orange power is completely incompatible with the Violet. Having less weaknesses than most rings, the ring has a stronger control over its wielder.
- **Indigo:** Indigo rings are fueled by compassion, and its users are ambassadors of goodwill. The Indigo power wielders can replicate unique abilities of other rings colors, as long as bearers of the other active rings are around. The indigo power can be transmuted into different ring energies but the transfer of Indigo power is much less efficient and limits what abilities can be used by the other color wielder. (A Green ring bearer takes a "simulated energy" charge from and Indigo power staff. Their ring will recharge and be capable of energy projection but may not be able to fly.)
- **White:** The white Power is the most powerful of all of the emotional color spectrum. The White power is energized by the power of the Life Entity. It has the power to completely override/augment all other color rings. The White power destroys the Black power, releasing the previously dead wielder from their control.
- **Black:** The Black power is an extradimensional energy fueled by death and had its origins from the being known as Nekron. The Black energy is completely incompatible with all other energies of the emotional spectrum and can even be destroyed if more than one of those energies are used in concert against it. The Black power can also be neutralized by the presence of the White power.

**It is theoretically possible for a single ring wielder to use more than one ring. Several people have been privy to having access to more than one color at different times in their career. (Sinestro has been a Green Lantern, and a Yellow ring-wielder. Hal Jordan has also used the Green and Yellow powers.)**

- But it has never been seen for a single user to use more than one ring color at one time. In Green Lantern lore, wearing more than one ring has no boosting of effect or ability for the wielder.)
- Think of the use of a ring as a form of psychic bonding of the ring's power with the wielder. It requires a concentration on the state of mind necessary to use that ring and a complete ability to maintain that state. Since most of these emotional states are conflicting, it becomes very difficult to see a person ABLE to use more than one color at a time. Only a significantly greater power, such as the White or Black Powers could completely override a ring-bearer's personal connection with their ring.
- Other colors may erode or reduce a ring's effectiveness (Yellow or Orange, for example) but cannot supplant that ring-bearer unless their connection to their ring is completely broken.

Comment: Kyle Rayner has worn all of the rings at once in the new 52. Didn't last long. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_Rayner#The_New_52

Comment: I read that story and decided Kyle Rayner has been an exception to the rule more often than not. So I am going to insist it is more of a plot device than a true bonding of the rings to his person. Some of the writing in the New 52 has been questionable, at best.

Comment: Don't forget that a) Blue rings are almost incapable of exerting their power unless in the presence of a Green Ring (hope is nothing without the will to use it) and b) Hal Jordan once wore a blue and green ring at the same time.  They interfered with each other to the point where Hal could barely fly, but his Green ring stayed at or above 200% power the whole time.

Comment: Not only did Kyle wield all the rings at once (becoming a White Lantern), he's been shown creating multi-colored constructs. And any time he creates a white construct, he's technically using all the colors at one time. I can't find a specific example, but I very clearly remember a year or so ago a scene with him creating multi-colored constructs.

Answer (score 7):

While this is pure speculation on my part, as noted in my comments to the question, I would have to answer with a resounding "Kinda, sorta, probably not".

In my recollection, there has not been an attempt to fuse the powers/aspects of specifically two rings. So that's a "No" to the question as stated. However, Kyle Rayner did manage to master the range of the emotional spectrum (all seven colors) and combine them with his own ring to become a White Lantern. It's possible that the colors of the spectrum can only combine all at once, rather than in a one-with-one fashion. This would neatly avert the issue of "Red + Green = Yellow, right?".

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The answer is yes. Notice Hal Jordan rocking Orange AND Yellow. And next to that is Guy Gardner rocking Red AND Star Sapphire. Both these guys are wearing two rings and they're using the powers of both rings simultaneously. From: *Emerald Warriors* #10 (May 25, 2011)

If I'm being totally honest though, I just found that Googling "two Lantern Rings." What I have actually READ is one of the most important events in recent DC print: *Darkest Night* (2009-2010), and won't soon forget Guy turning into a Black Lantern meat grinder when Kyle Rayner died.

[image]

There are other instances of two rings being worn simultaneously and in most one can see one color being dominant based on the dominant emotion (i.e. Guy in the above picture have more Red than Green due to his rage over Kyle's death surpassing his will as a seasoned combatant). Hal and Guy in the first photo are consciously channeling both equally as they had a mission to accomplish, picking the Rings themselves, which is extraordinary as the Power Ring(s) generally find a suitable member to their respective Corps.

I present Harley Quinn rocking a Black/Red ring. You read that right two corps, one ring. From: *Harley’s Little Black Book* #2. (February 10, 2016) Notice her coloring is not only equal, but it is checkered, I would take that to mean that the merged ring keeps the wearer evenly powered (yes, the rings have unique powers) and is more intrinsic to the ring as it's colors are visually woven together. But perhaps I am reading too much into it.

[image]

Comment: Also I don't think this actually answers the question of "has anyone made one ring that combines will and fear". You seem to be answering "has anyone ever wielded two rings at once".

Comment: I show two rings can be wielded at once, two rings can be simultaneously used, and Harley's ring, though it would seem a unique item thus far in DC cannon, demonstrates that yes indeed two rings can be merged into one, giving the bearer the powers of both. If the question is solely, with the exclusion of any evidence supporting ability to produce one, "has a ring ever been made, and used, in DC cannon merging the Green and Sinestro Power Rings?" I suppose a simple, "Nope," would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think so because in a Harley Quin side  story a red and black ring or combined into one ring and Harley gets her hands on it.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: Her ring was black and red and combined rage and fear. http://cdn.hitfix.com/photos/6210482/HARLEYLBB_2_7.jpg.

Comment: @Valorum - I thought yellow was fear?

Comment: @Adamant - Black Lantern rings augment the wearer's dominant emotions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes and No.

No one ever made a ring with the intent to have it charged with 2 different colors in the spectrum.

However, the rings themselves take a charge from whatever lantern that they're programed to or whatever energy source they can and it's not like they change the energy from one color to the other. So they can hold any charge they want technically...

And further, before the GL corps were killed by Hal, Ion and Parallax were both in the same battery and the two colors were "combined" which produced the Yellow weakness.

The White rings are poweredd by the whole spectrum so they were cobined there. They were largely "unmixed" though so it is effectively wearing a green and yellow ring at the same time like Hal and Sinestro has done at various points.

This does raise the question of why no one has ever tried to mix Green and Blue though.