# Are there vampires in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, vampire, star-trek-eu

Let us characterize vampires as a humanoid being that drinks the blood of other humanoid beings to create more of their species. There are many aliens that are humanoid in the Star Trek universe. My question is: in all the books, movies, comics and TV shows, are there any vampires?

Comment: Related closed question: [Could the Enterprise beam a vampire into a house she didn’t have permission to enter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/could-the-enterprise-beam-a-vampire-into-a-house-she-didnt-have-permission-to-e/6760#6760)

Comment: One obvious choice would be Klingons.  They drink bloodwine.  They eat Rokeg blood pie.  While being tormented with painsticks Worf admits that he "craves only the blood of the enemy."  Kang declared that he would cut out an enemy's heart and eat it.  Gagh, a Klingon delicacy, is serpent worms, served alive, bloody and moving.  Klingons are the most consistently bloodthirsty of all the Trek aliens.  God help the Federation if the Klingons ever run out of non-humanoids to slake their neverending thirst for blood.

Comment: Salt Vampires, yes.

Comment: @KyleJones the difference, however, appears to be that Klingons drink blood as a *cultural* habit, not from any specific biological need or process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes and no.

The closest we come in the ***main canon*** (e.g. TV and Films) is the TOS episode "[Obsession](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Obsession_%28episode%29)" where we encounter a creature known as a "[Dikironium Cloud](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dikironium_cloud_creature)". It  certainly meets most of the main criteria you've described...

> **GARROVICK:** *Sir, **that thing only feeds on blood**.*
>   **KIRK:** *Garrovick, get back to the ship. Tell them to prepare to detonate.*
>   **GARROVICK:** *Captain, you're not going to be the bait.*

and

> **SPOCK:** *Doctor, **evidence indicates the creature is here to spawn**. If so, it will reproduce by fission, not just into two parts, but
>   thousands.*    ...
>   **MCCOY:** *I presume you intend to use that haemoplasm to attract the creature?*
>   **KIRK:** *We must get it to the antimatter. **It seems attracted to red blood cells**. What better bait could we have?*

Obviously it's not even close to being humanoid.

[image]

Other creatures fit some elements of vampirism, notably the "incubus" seen in TNG : "[Sub Rosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_Rosa_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29)" (which drains the subject of **psychic energy** and periodically assumes human form)

[image]

and the M-113 creature seen in TOS: "[The Man Trap](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Man_Trap_%28episode%29)" (which drains several crew-members of their **salt**)

[image]

---

Elsewhere in the EU canon, there was a crossover that featured a **genuine** vampire named Britt. She helped the Enterprise crew fight off an [infestation of Zombies](http://blog.paxholley.net/2013/10/17/awesome-tober-fest-2013-idws-infestation-event-2011/) in the TOS Comic: "[Infestation, Issue 1](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Infestation,_Issue_1)"

[image]

You might also want to take a look at the TOS novel "[Bloodthirst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodthirst_%28novel%29)" (hat tip to @Omegacron) where Kirk and the crew encounter a manmade virus which causes its victims to suffer from many of the more obvious characteristics of vampirism, notably a thirst for blood and extreme light sensitivity.

> There is only the outpost's sole survivor, Dr. Jeffrey Adams. A man
>   with a secret that will rock the very foundations of Starfleet... and
>   a terrible, all-consuming hunger that will bring death to the crew of
>   the starship Enterprise.

[image]

Comment: What is the Baroness doing in there!?

Comment: @AndresF. - "*Without giving too much away, I can say that we start in the IDW universe with a zombie outbreak of epic proportions. The threat is contained (or is it?), but not before it infests other realities - the realities of our licensed books. The individual series will show just how **our intrepid heroes - folks like Optimus Prime, Dr. Peter Venkman, Mr. Spock, Baroness, and so many others** - face down this new and obviously shocking threat, and their desperate efforts to stop it before it can completely consume - both literally and figuratively - their realities."*

Comment: Fascinating . . .

Comment: @hikaruichijyo - I think you mean "fascinating (followed by eyebrow lift)"

Comment: @AndresF.: Looking sexy. That's what she always does.

Comment: Also, props on the ridiculous amount of nipplage in that image. Who drew it, Hugh Hefner? I've been to strip clubs with the air conditioning on full bore and never seen that many erect nipples.